# How to capture thumbnails (frame) from video with HTML5 and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have a simple block in which I would like to capture a frame from video every 5 seconds and display them something like this below.

[image]

Here is a solution I have tried.

```
<video id="video" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
    </source>
</video>

<div id="time-ruler"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<div id="thumbnailContainer"></div>
```

Here is javascript

```
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    var duration = video.duration;
    var i = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        video.currentTime = i;
        generateThumbnail(i);
        i = i+5;
        if (i > duration) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 300);
});

function generateThumbnail(i) {
    //generate thumbnail URL data
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 220, 150);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    //create img
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', dataURL);

    //append img in container div
    document.getElementById('thumbnailContainer').appendChild(img);
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ndhgp1ae/)

Unfortunately, this is not working as expected.

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/psbqn9d0/1/

It won't create the view you shown in the picture, but will change the thumbnail every 5 second. I have also added few logging to help you understand the code.

Now, if you want to achieve what is shown in figure then this is possible:-

1. if you have loaded the video completely. Then create all the thumbnails and add them to the container.
2. you create the thumbnails on the server and send them to user (like done by most video sites (so we can see what is in the video without loading!))
3. OR you can create all the thumbnails without loading the whole video. I am not sure if this is the best way, but this will definitely work.

You should create another `video` tag with the same source link, and hide it using css. Then you will create a javascript function which will seek it to every 5th second programmatically and keep saving the thumbnails and adding them in your container. This way, your thumbnails will be generated for the whole video without loading the whole video.

I hope it clarifies your doubts!

Comment: Thanks a lot let me check out, I will come back, to escape downvote please include your code here in your answer, very good explanation

Comment: @user9964622 Please edit the answer and include the code if it works for you, else put a downvote... I can't escape my destiny :(

Comment: @user9964622 If it doesn't resolves your issue, you are welcome to ask for clarification.

Comment: ok, got you, what about displaying time(interval of 5 seconds) of thumbnails as form a ruler is it possible?

Comment: @user9964622 It is definitely possible, but as I said, its mostly done by creating the thumbnails on the server and then sending them out... I will edit the answer to include the third way I described in the answer after a while.. maybe that will help you!

Comment: Hi I solve the issue with thumbnails, thanks, if you will have some time check this ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726973/how-to-create-slider-which-contain-time-ruler-using-javascript